# Getting Error Unexpected Token When Trying to Save Apps Script Code. Running 3 OnEdits in a single file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am attaching a screen shot of the error I am getting when trying to run this code. I will put the code below as well. It says Line 9 has the error.

**Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' line: 9 file: Code.gs**
***Below is what I have:***

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "ACTIVITY REPORT" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.values == "TRUE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11 && (e.value == 'NP CND A ACCEPTED' || e.value == 'NP BACKGROUND') {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    e.range.offset(0, 16).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11) {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    if (e.range.getValue() == 'NP CND A ACCEPTED' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP BACKGROUND' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED INTERN-SP' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED SDR-SP' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED INTERN' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED SDR' || e.range.getValue() == 'HIRED SDR' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP AS' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP LDR' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP CND A AR' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP CND A OFFER' || e.range.getValue() == 'NO SHOW' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP ORL' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP CND A Zoom Int' || e.range.getValue() == 'NP CND A 1 FL')
      e.range.offset(0, 14).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

[Image of code with error message at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV49A.png)

Comment: Yeah it looks like kind of a mess.  I think I'd rewrite it using an array and use an indexOf().

Comment: Your missing a close parenthesis `'NP BACKGROUND') ) {` on line 9.  Probably more typos but I didn't check.

Comment: @TheWizEd I adjusted that but it still isn't working. I don't get an error code except when I click Debug it pulls up this.                                                                 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: You can't run onEdit(e) from script editor.  e is undefined.

Comment: @TheWizEd So, when I test this out on my actual spreadsheet it still doesn't work. Am I needing to edit the name of the function? Remove the e?

Comment: No, e contains the range and value.  Instead of `e.range.getValue()` you could use `e.value`. You are comparing `e.value` with strings.  Any difference will result in false.  A typo, a space at the end, a tab in between characters.  Are you sure e.value is identical to any of the match strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "ACTIVITY REPORT" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11 && (e.value == 'NP CND A ACCEPTED' || e.value == 'NP BACKGROUND')) {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    e.range.offset(0, 16).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Archive' && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 11) {
    let ops = ['NP CND A ACCEPTED', 'NP BACKGROUND', 'HIRED INTERN-SP', 'HIRED SDR-SP', 'HIRED', 'HIRED INTERN', 'HIRED SDR', 'HIRED SDR', 'NP AS', 'NP LDR', 'NP CND A AR', 'NP CND A OFFER', 'NO SHOW', 'NP ORL', 'NP CND A Zoom Int', 'NP CND A 1 FL'];
    if (~ops.indexOf(e.value)) {
      e.range.offset(0, 14).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there something that would cause the row from activity report to go the very bottom of the archive page and not just go right under the last row that was archived?